# motd - UNIX - AIX - different welcome screens for diff users

Tags: shell-script, scripting, aix

is it possible to segregate different motd files for different users ? 
 So Admin gets a different message and others diff one....

Comment: Dumb question: Why don't you put the display command in ~/.profile or ~/.kshrc (or ~/.bashrc or whatever shell you use for each user) ?

Comment: we Use LDAP in the Environment..  which uses /etc/.profile  for all the users...   
in normal environment we have .profile in the /home/users/$id/ directory... 
which is not... in my case...

Comment: You should have added such details to the original question, how are others supposed to know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search, I came up with the idea:

edit the /etc/profile and add the below loop to the end but before TRAP..

```
#!/bin/ksh
ROOTY=$(whoami)
if [ ${ROOTY} != root ] ; then
    for i in `who am i |awk {'print $1'}` 
    do
        RID=$i
        UNIXADM=$(sudo cat /home/root/unixusers | grep -Fx $RID | wc -l)
        if [ ${UNIXADM} == 1 ] ; then
            cat /etc/motd.unixusers
        fi
    done
fi
```

where  /home/root/unixusers  will be the user list
/etc/motd.unixusers is the user specific motd

Answer (score 1):

that looks over complex to me

```
ROOTY=$(whoami)
if [ ${ROOTY} != root ]
then
   if sudo grep -q $ROOTY /home/root/unixusers
   then cat /etc/motd.unixusers
   else cat /etc/motd
   fi
fi
```

please note that

- `whoami` and `who am i |awk {'print $1'}` are likely to give same result
- `sudo cat /home/root/unixusers | grep -Fx $RID | wc -l` is equivalent to `sudo grep -c $RID /home/root/unixusers`
- however, you compare to 1, why not take result from grep ?
- why run a loop for one item ?

Comment: test123:root:/home/root # who am i
sivas123     pts/0       18 Sep 11:59     (test.test.com)
test123:root:/home/root # whoami
root
test123:root:/home/root #

Comment: who am i    &  whoami  are two different commands   @jeff Schaller

I have to make sure, only the users in the list has to get the message...
not every user in the server... only specific users in the list...  so when i cat and grep with -Fx it will be the exact match in the list.. and the count will be either 0 or 1..  so if it is 1 then message displays.. 0 no message..   and when you sudo su to root... same profile is loaded in LDAP environment...  so i have to make sure.. this for loop should not display the motd... during sudoing......    make sense ?   ;-)

Comment: Interesting, I never have use ldap environment in Linux (now I have to), thus maybe `who am i | awk '{print $1}'`  and `whoami` give two differente result.